# A JavaScript error on the site

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I get the following error when loading the magento stackexchange site.

```
Magento Stack Exchange requires external JavaScript from another domain,
which is blocked or failed to load.
```

What does it mean? 
Is it something blocked from my end?

Comment: You might want to check out the "And what else do I need" section of [the post about browsers and technologies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/131713) on the network meta.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have strict security settings in you browser. I don't think there's something you have to worry about.